# Handle menu event in C# MVP

Tags: c#, mvp

I am learning C# and MVP. I am able to handle simple menu click event. What I am trying to handle menu click event using MVP pattern and not able to figure out why its not working. I have looked at a lot of code on internet and came up with the below.

```
interface IMenuBarView
{
    event EventHandler AboutMenuItemClicked;
    ...
}

public partial class MenuBarView : UserControl, IMenuBarView
{
    public event EventHandler AboutMenuItemClicked;
    private MenuBarPresenter m_menuBarPresenter;

    public MenuBarView()
    {
        this.aboutToolStripMenuItem.Click += AboutMenuItemClicked;
        m_menuBarPresenter = new MenuBarPresenter(this);
    }
}

class MenuBarPresenter
{
    private IMenuBarView m_menuView;

    public MenuBarPresenter(IMenuBarView menu)
    {
        m_menuView = menu;
        m_menuView.AboutMenuItemClicked += AboutMenuItemClicked;
    }
    public  void AboutMenuItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
}
```

I can have a event handler in the MenuBarView and which in turn can call the presenter to do the logic. But I am more interested in doing is the one above. Is that not the right way of doing it ?
I am really really new to C#, so don't kill me. :)

**After Edit:**
I quickly made up something which I tried compiling as per @Enigmativity comments. It runs but the event is never called. Create a form, add a menu item and give the menu item name as item1ToolStripMenuItem. When clicking the menu, the event is not fired.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testEventHandler
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form, IMenuBarView
    {
        public event EventHandler AboutMenuItemClicked;
        private MenuBarPresenter m_menuBarPresenter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.item1ToolStripMenuItem.Click += AboutMenuItemClicked;
            m_menuBarPresenter = new MenuBarPresenter(this);
        }


    }

    interface IMenuBarView
    {
        event EventHandler AboutMenuItemClicked;
    }

    class MenuBarPresenter
    {
        private IMenuBarView m_menuView;
        public MenuBarPresenter(IMenuBarView menu)
        {
            m_menuView = menu;
            m_menuView.AboutMenuItemClicked += item1ToolStripMenuItem_Click;
        }
        private void item1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be really useful if the code you post actually compiles and it would be great to know, other than that, what "not working" means with your actual code.

Comment: I thought to post smallest amount of code so that whoever look can tell if this is a good code or not. Not working means I do not get the control inside AboutMenuItemClicked.

Comment: What does "I do not get the control inside AboutMenuItemClicked" mean?

Comment: Also, you should post a [mcve]. Smallest amount code is good as long it contains everything sufficient for us to see the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with the order of your commands.

When you write this:

```
        this.item1ToolStripMenuItem.Click += this.AboutMenuItemClicked;
```

You are saying "any handers attached to `this.AboutMenuItemClicked` should be ***copied*** to `this.item1ToolStripMenuItem.Click`". There are no attached handlers at the time. You are copying nothing.

Then you call `m_menuBarPresenter = new MenuBarPresenter(this);` which attaches `item1ToolStripMenuItem_Click` to the `this.AboutMenuItemClicked` event delegate.

If you swap the order it works:

```
        m_menuBarPresenter = new MenuBarPresenter(this);
        this.item1ToolStripMenuItem.Click += this.AboutMenuItemClicked;
```

However, this isn't the right way to attach events. You shouldn't need to care if someone has attached or handler.

```
        this.item1ToolStripMenuItem.Click += (s, e) => this.AboutMenuItemClicked?.Invoke(s, e);
        m_menuBarPresenter = new MenuBarPresenter(this);
```

That's the correct way.

The `?.Invoke` calls `.Invoke` if there is a subscriber, but if there isn't it does nothing.

---

I've also had a play with your code. This is closer to how I would do MVP:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler AboutMenuItemClicked;
    private Presenter _presenter;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.item1ToolStripMenuItem.Click += (s, e) => this.AboutMenuItemClicked?.Invoke(s, e);

        _presenter = new Presenter(this);
    }

    public void ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}

interface IMenuBarView
{
    event EventHandler AboutMenuItemClicked;
}

class Presenter
{
    private readonly Form1 _form;
    private readonly AlertModel _alertModel;

    public Presenter(Form1 form)
    {
        _form = form;
        _form.AboutMenuItemClicked += _form_AboutMenuItemClicked;
        _alertModel = new AlertModel();
        _alertModel.Message += _alertModel_Message;
    }

    private void _alertModel_Message(object sender, string e)
    {
        _form.ShowMessage(e);
    }

    private void _form_AboutMenuItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _alertModel.UpdateModel("About Menu Item");
    }
}

class AlertModel
{
    public event EventHandler<string> Message;

    public void UpdateModel(string action)
    {
        this.Message?.Invoke(this, $"User has selected \"{action}\"");
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the order worked!
What is this construct called if I want to read about it ?
this.item1ToolStripMenuItem.Click += (s, e) => this.AboutMenuItemClicked?.Invoke(s, e);

I got your version of code. Kind of full flow from view -> presenter -> model -> presenter -> view I think. Less chances of missing out something. I think it will take sometime for me to get used to this.

Comment: @nav - Look up anonymous functions.